# ValidationError: ["'' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."] in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x

when I initiate the request for the date field name as dob with the respective value of dob is "dob":"1996-10-25"

Model.py

```
class Register_model(models.Model):
    UserId = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='',blank=True,null=True)
    ISpinId = models.CharField(max_length=255,primary_key=True, unique=True,default='', blank=True,null = False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="",null = False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="",null = False)
    dob = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=False,null = False)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="",null = False)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="",null = False)
```

views.py

```
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
class User_RegisterAPIViews(APIView):
    # Serializer Initilization
    print("dasf")
    serializers = serializers.Register_Serializer

    # Post method Declarations
    def post(self, request):
        request.POST._mutable = True
        print(request.data)
        request.data['ISpinId'] = etc.random_number_generate(request.data['first_name'], request.data['last_name'])
        password = request.data['password']
        print(request.data['dob'])
        playersCategory, age = etc.age_convert(request.data['dob'], request.data['gender'])
        request.data['players_category'] = playersCategory
        request.data['age'] = age

        form_data = serializers.Register_Serializer(data=request.data)
        if form_data.is_valid():
            print("formdata",form_data)
            form_data.save()  # File Save
```

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 497, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 457, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 468, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 494, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/srfi-api/User/views.py", line 69, in post
    form_data.save()  # File Save
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 213, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 932, in create
    instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 422, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 741, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 779, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 870, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 908, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1186, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1334, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1278, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1278, in <listcomp>
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1277, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1218, in prepare_value
    value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 789, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1273, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1268, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "/home/shawn-codoid/Music/virtual/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1243, in to_python
    params={'value': value},
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]
[03/Oct/2019 12:29:15] "POST /api/register/ HTTP/1.1" 500 214929
```

I create a new database, Database migrations, and I also apply new migrations but still, I got this error ["'' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]

Comment: You are using DRF. use this: 'DATE_INPUT_FORMATS': ['%d-%m-%Y'], in REST_FRAMEWORK dictionary in settings.py or you can change date formate here. I had same problem and this solution worked for me. Also "auto_now_add" and "auto_now" is False by default. you don't have to mention that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your model any date filed parameter like default value empty quotes replaced by

```
model.DateField(blank= True,null=True)
```